# Send Slack notification every time a Status is changed in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, slack-api

I have a Status Notification class, so that when a status is created it sends me a slack message.The issue I am running into is that a new status is created every few minutes and getting a slack message every couple minutes is repetitive and nonconstructive. Especially because there are dozens of servers posting these statuses.

Would there be a way to only post the slack message if a specific servers status has changed? e.g. server was up then went down.

I've tried getting all of the server statuses but cant figure out how to only get the last two with a specific server id.

---------------------------------------------------------EDITS------------------------------------------------------------
Previously tried attempt: except the last else I wouldn't want there

```
 $statuses = ServerStatus::all();
    $first = ServerStatus::where('server_id', $notifiable->server_id)->first();
    //dump($first);

    foreach($statuses as $status){
        if($status->server_id === $notifiable->server_id){
            //dump($status);
            if($status->status_id !== $first->status_id){
                return (new SlackMessage)
                    ->content('One of your statuses has been updated!');
            }
            else{
                return (new SlackMessage)
                    ->content('One of your statuses has been not updated!');
            }
        }
    }
```

also my boot for sending the notification every time a ServerStatus is created:

protected static function boot(){

```
    parent::boot();

    ServerStatus::created(function($model) {

        $original = ServerStatus::where('server_id', $model->server_id)->skip(1)->first();

        dump('original',$original->status_id);
        dump('serverStatus', $model->status_id);

        if ($original && $model->status_id != $original->status_id) {
            $model->notify(new ServerStatusNotification());
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure - fetch the previous status and compare it.

Comment: I'm not sure how the migration helps here.  You haven't shown how the notification is initiated.  Why don't you just query in the notification class to see if the last status matches, if it does, don't send the notification.

Comment: Would I use a pluck to fetch the previous status because when I ran dd(ServerStatus::pluck('server_id','status_id')) it only returned the most recent state of each server. This is then overwritten by the new state and virtually useless for me? correct? (Fairly new to laravel in general so sorry if this sounds trivial)

Comment: This should be a fairly basic query.  If you're trying to use pluck without any conditions, I think you have a lot more reading to do.  I suggest you read through Laravel.com/docs.  It's very well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bind to the `updating` event in the boot function of your `ServerStatus` model so you can make an `isDirty` comparison. You can call `isDirty('status_id')` to determine if the status id has been changed, something like this:

```
protected static function boot() 
{

    parent::boot();

    ServerStatus::created(function(ServerStatus $serverStatus) {
        $original = ServerStatus::where('server_id', $serverStatus->server_id)->last();
        if ($original && $serverStatus->status_id !== $original->status_id) {
            // send slack notification, status id differs
        }
    });
}
```

If you need more control over the specific status, you can call `getOriginal()` to get the original value and determine, such as in your case, the specific status transitions:

```
ServerStatus::created(function(ServerStatus $serverStatus) {
    $original = ServerStatus::where('server_id', $serverStatus->server_id)->last();

    if ($original && $original->status->description === 'up' && $serverStatus->status->description === 'down') {
        //send server went down notification
    } else if ($original && $original->status->description === 'down' && $serverStatus->status->description === 'up') {
        //send server is up notification
    }
});
```

I don't actually know what your relationship name is, or the column that stores the text version of the `status` is, but something like the above should work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much I was trying to do most of my logic in the notification class itself so that helps me a ton! After implementing the first one, im not getting any slack messages at all, I will trouble shoot some and let you know.

Comment: Would this work even though they are creating a brand new model everytime the status is updated? Not just updating the database entry?

Comment: @Striker So a new `ServerStatus` model is being created every time the status is updated? If that's the case, this will not work at all, because there was no original and `isDirty` would fail everytime. You would need to get the previous `ServerStatus` in the `creating` function instead of` updating`

Comment: Yes a new ServerStatus is being created every time. I attached what I tried previously, its probably way off but I figured it may help.

Comment: @Striker Updated, this may be more useful to you

Comment: I'm giving that a shot, are you sure its last()  wouldn't it be first(). I changed it to first and die and dumped both the variables after noticing it sent the message everytime i created on still. WHat was odd was the the `$serverStatus->status_id` and the `$original->status_id` both were 2 just server status was a string and original was a int.

Comment: added a photo of dd and what I currently have for boot

Comment: got it working! the completed version is added above!